# Make flags (for mod attention) archivable

Tags: feature-request, moderator-abilities

It'd be nice to be able to "archive" (or mark as read) flags instead of just removing them, to be able to review them in the future, and see for example what was the action taken by another mod.

Sometimes I see a flag asking to delete an answer or a question, and I'm not quite sure so I don't take action, only to see the flag later removed, not remembering what post it was to see if a fellow mod delete it or desestimated it like me.

It could be useful to have that list of flags in a post for reference also, now I'm annotating users but it just doesn't seem to be the correct place to leave this reminders, and it also doesn't solve losing transparency on other mods' actions.

Comment: It looks like the flags are actually stored. Clearing them removes them from visibility in the top bar, but if the same post gets a new flag, you can see the earlier flags that were cleared as well.

Comment: Good to know @Grace, having a new "archived" tab shouldn't be so difficult then :)

Comment: It would also help when the mods change on a site, so we can see what previous mods have done. In a similar vein, I've put in a feature request for [the ability to annotate flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78735/149375).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has now been partially implemented. Moderators now can track the history of flags both from a user, and upon a user. The former is identical to when a user checks their own flag report from their flag weight.

Answer (score 3):

This has now been implemented [more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59932/make-flags-for-mod-attention-archivable/85921#85921). If a post has been flagged, then the `mod` dialog on the post offers an option to `show flag history`. The number next to the button is the number of flags that were ever left on the post.

[image: mod button dialog]

Comment: I love screens from moderator's interface :)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the post or either user involved (flagger or flaggee), then you can use the tools described other answers.

Failing that -- you remember there was a flag but you can't find the post -- you can look in the recent history of other moderators.  The moderator dashboard (no screenshot here in public) shows you when each moderator last took mod actions; that timestamp is a link to a reverse-chronological log of actions.  I sometimes use this approach -- use the timestamps to identify the best candidates, and then look at each until I find it.

That works ok on a site with 3 moderators, but it's kind of a pain even on medium-sized sites, let alone large ones.  It would be great if the flags page had a link to recently-handled flags, which would be a mashup of those per-person logs I mentioned all into one list.  It could be limited to the last few days if performance is a concern.