# Who has the power to delete a comment?

Tags: support, comments, comment-flags, deleted-comments

I posted a comment on the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822227/aligning-three-span-div-tags-fixed-left-fixed-right-fill-middle). My comment was:

> You will have to work on your [accept rate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Currently it's catastrophic. Zero as in a singularity inside a black hole.

This comment was deleted by someone. I would like to know if showing users that don't know how to accept answers is considered as a bad thing so that I stop doing it or if not why would my comment have been deleted and do only moderators are InRole to delete comments.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66773/should-mods-delete-work-on-that-accept-rate-comments) [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23321/is-it-appropriate-to-comment-on-peoples-accept-rate)

Comment: Also, [The Power is yours!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Planet_and_the_Planeteers) :P

Comment: At least your original comment included a link that explains what "accept rate" means. Most of them that I see (and all of the ones that I personally flag) don't even go that far. How is someone who doesn't know about accept rate supposed to do in response to comments like that? Answer: Feel like this site is a hostile place with high-rep users who don't want to help.

Comment: Do I get a notification for deleted comments? Or is it like if it never happened? Even its history gets deleted?

Comment: @Roberto Seems like the comments just vanish into thin air. I actually came here wondering about comment deletion rules, as I've had some I *think* got deleted, but I have literally no feedback about it. I actually reposted a couple because afaik they were acceptable as comments (e.g., feedback about a question) and also it's entirely within possibility that I just typed it and forget to ever hit "add comment" (squirrel!!). I see lots of linked questions showing general confusion over comments, so it seems to be something of a general site problem.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are three ways that a comment can get deleted.

- A user can delete their own comment.
- A moderator can delete anyone's comments. (see also [A guide to moderating comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237978))
- Any user with at least 15 reputation can flag a comment, and enough flags can cause the deletion of that comment. (see also [How does comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17364))

People have been somewhat less tolerant of "accept rate" comments, so it is highly likely that your comment was simply subject to enough flags.

Comment: I said people have been less tolerant of those comments, I should've qualified that it is usually because of their scathing nature and an otherwise lack of contribution. People need to be taught somehow, but there are many ways to accomplish that.

Comment: please be more precise. What is the well established code in this situation? Ctrl+W or a polite comment?

Comment: There isn't a well-established code, @Darin. There are multiple approaches. Some people are in fact very creative in how they spur users to accept answers. I'd say politeness usually is helpful.

Comment: OK, so if the community decided so please close my question as an exact duplicate.

Comment: How can people be "taught" if deletion of comments can be done without the poster's knowledge? Some moderator (or power user) just deleted a bunch of - admittedly chit-chat - comments, but I was only alerted to that by somebody else noticing the deletions and posting a comment about that. One can't learn from a mistake if one is never told it was a mistake...

Comment: Is there any way to see who removed your comment?

Comment: enough flags means? How many flags?

Comment: @MarjanVenema Apparently some comments that are otherwise fine may be deleted when they're no longer needed (there's a flag for that). But they aren't scrutinized much, according to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368426/18115206). But I agree that we should be notified when doing something wrong, even in a comment (hopefully in a polite and civil way). And at the same time we shouldn't worry too much about it, as the linked answer also says.

Comment: @xaxxon I don't believe there is, not sure about mods. As JamieB comments in the question, they seem to vanish into thin air. I was wondering if I'd commented on a different site when I couldn't see it in my All actions list.

Comment: @DamithRuwan 3 or more and sometimes just 1 if it contains some keyword from an undisclosed list according to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381068/18115206).

Answer (score 37):

Without giving too much away, there are certain heuristics that make some types of comments a bit, shall we say, *easier* to flag away than others.

=8-D

Comment: related: [What is the SE version of Seven Dirty Words?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238835/997587)