# Global flag history tab for moderator tools

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, moderation, moderator-tools

In the moderator tools, there is a flag queue, and flags can be dismissed as valid/invalid.  However, sometimes I want to review recent flags, whether I or another moderator acted upon it.  I'm aware of `http://stackexchangesite.com/admin/history` but that just shows individual moderator actions, not *just* flags.

However, this list could become unwieldly on larger SE sites, such as Stack Overflow.  [Robert Harvey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/102937/robert-harvey) suggested using a "star system" (similar to chat) as a way of pinning certain flags for other moderators' attention.

Another idea is just to show the flag history for, say, the past week or month?  Or have options for day, week, month, year, etc., and it would be more manageable.

Possible reasons for a flag history:

- See who has flagged a particular post (now in the post history)
- Go back and see which mod took care of a particular flag - but can't remember which one (now in the post history)
- For further discussion
- For future reference
- Etc.

Is this a good idea?  What do you think?  I personally would benefit from having a history, it is nice to have them all in one place, even if acted on/dismissed.

Comment: Related: [Make flags for moderator attention archivable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59932/make-flags-for-mod-attention-archivable)

Comment: There have been significant updates here.  1 and 2 you can get from the post's mod menu.  The history page has also been updated.  Perhaps you could update this to reflect the current state of the request?

Comment: The history linked from the post is very useful.  Usually when I want to review, though, I don't remember which post it was -- just that, hey, we had a flag about a long comment thread, and there was that NAA/valid argument, and on another I left a comment and left the flag activve to check back in a day for updates from the OP, etc -- but I don't necessarily remember where they were, because I interacted with them from the flag queue, not from normal browsing.